# images repository in GCP

Tags: images, cloud-storage, google

I'm wondering what options do I have if I consider to build image/logo repository in GCP (Google Cloud Platform) from which users will be able to pull while working with Looker. I'm looking into most ideal solution. I was considering:

- empty html, with image link in base64 - not ideal as link generated is long
- using bucket storage - from what I understand access need to be given to everyone?
- signed url - need to be refreshed after 7 days
- storing in BigQuery - needs to have created a service account that will query it

I'm also thinking of using Docker, but I need to research more of this topic.

Could you please help? Are there any other options that I can use?

Thank you in advance and sorry if my question is not clear, this is the first time I'm asking something in this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you exactly looking for Google Cloud Storage, where you can create a bucket in Google Cloud Storage and set the appropriate permissions to allow users to access images. You can also use signed URLs to provide temporary access to specific files. - This solution is most likely in software systems and overall file storing which may be used somewhere else.

Your question isn't clear about what you want to archive, as far I understand you have files and you wish to share them with your users.

Comment: Hi, yes. Thank you for answering! I want to share these files (images/logos) with my users in most efficient way.

Comment: Personally I would just use Google Drive in some way, if you need to do that programmatically (for example through selling platform or something) it's recommended to use Object Storage ala Amazon S3 in this case Google Cloud Storage. I think you were a bit mislead in a selection of technology. You can also think about solutions like WeTransfer to send a file to single person.